Is it possible to display a base64 docx file in React?
I'm receiving documents from an API as a base64 string, and would like to display this in the browser.
Is anyone aware of a way to display this base64 docx file?
I've tried various packages to do this but they seem to only work if provided with a URL to a file that is either hosted online, or stored locally.

"if provided with a URL to a file" - Have you tried constructing a data URL from the Base64 data?

Yes, it is possible. You can use library mammoth.js to convert docx to HTML. Mammoth is designed to convert .docx documents directly but you need to write an additional few lines of code for the base64 docx.
Install Mammoth
npm install mammoth

Then use it in your React component
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import mammoth from 'mammoth';

const DocxDisplay = ({ base64Docx } /* Your base64 encoded string */) => {

    const [htmlContent, setHtmlContent] = useState('');

    const convertDocxToHtml = () => {
        const byteCharacters = atob(base64Docx);
        const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
        const blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' });

        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = async function (e) {
            const arrayBuffer = reader.result;
            const result = await mammoth.convertToHtml({ arrayBuffer });
            setHtmlContent(result.value); // Set HTML content
        }

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={convertDocxToHtml}>Display DOCX Content</button>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlContent }} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default DocxDisplay;

